# NodeJS Output user in browser

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I made a project where i include database which i wrote on mysql and it make a json file from database and also output all users in browser but I have some problem. I want to output one user how can i do this(this is example how it must output `http://localhost:8080/user/1`). I used express and mysql. Please help me. Thanks.

This is my code:

```
'use strict';
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const router = express()

// http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/fs.html#fs.writeFile
const fs = require('fs');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'lado',
    password: '1234'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM bankdb.account;', function(err, results, fields) {
    if(err) throw err;

    fs.writeFile('account.json', JSON.stringify(results), function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved!');
    });
    connection.end();
});


const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'lado',
    password: '1234',
    database: 'bankdb',
    charset: 'utf8'
});
var reo ='<html><head><title>Output From MYSQL</title></head><body><h1>Output From MYSQL</h1>{${table}}</body></html>';
function setResHtml(sql, cb){
    pool.getConnection((err, con)=>{
        if(err) throw err;

        con.query(sql, (err, res, cols)=>{
            if(err) throw err;

            var table =''; //to store html table

            //create html table with data from res.
            for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
                table +='<tr><td>' + (i+1) +'</td><td>'+ res[i].name +'</td><td>'+ res[i].address +'</td></tr>';
            }
            table ='<table border="1"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Amount</th></tr>'+ table +'</table>';

            con.release(); //Done with mysql connection

            return cb(table);
        });
    });
}

const sqll ='SELECT * FROM bankdb.account';

const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    setResHtml(sqll, resql=>{
        reo = reo.replace('{${table}}', resql);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
        res.write(reo, 'utf-8');
        res.end();
    });
});

server.listen(8080, ()=>{
    console.log('Server running at //localhost:8080/');
    router.get('/users/:id', function(req, res, next) {
        var user = users.getUserById(req.params.id);
        res.json(user);
    });
    exports.getUserById = function(id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i].id == id) return users[i];
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the specific user based on their id:

```
router.get( '/user/:id', function( req, res ) { // When visiting '/user/:id'

   var id = req.params.id; // For example if you visit localhost/user/24 the id will be 24

   connection.query('SELECT * FROM bankdb.account WHERE id=' + mysql.escape( id ), function(err, results, fields) {
       if(err) throw err;

       fs.writeFile('account.json', JSON.stringify(results), function (err) {
         if (err) throw err;
         console.log('Saved!');
       });
       connection.end();
   });

} );
```

If you grab every user from the database, your program will use up much more memory.

Just grab the one you need and work with him.

Comment: I shoud add it in `server.listen(8080, ()=>{...}` ? Cause when i add it here i show all users(I typed this `http://localhost:8080/user/1`) Sorry I'm just beginner

Comment: No worries. If I were you,  I would place this outside the `server.listen()`. I usually put all `router.get()` and `router.post()` etc. methods before `server.listen()`. Also, I do not know what your database looks like. Just make sure every user has an `id` field. That way you can search through the database based on their user id.

Comment: It should work properly. If you visit the website you will not get any response but a new file should be created.

Comment: Ooooh okay. Thanks)